# On a Mac: Can I create a key shortcut to run a bash code based on clipboard content

Tags: bash, macos, clipboard, spreadsheet

It has been a while since I coded a little bit and I only use Mac for a couple of weeks.

Here is what I would like to do:

I have a spreadsheet with email addresses, subjects and text bodies for an email. 
I can summarize this data in a way that I have a cell that is filled with

```
to=foo@nowhere.net,subject='test subject',body='test body'
```

Now, I would like to copy this line to clipboard and create a keyboard shortcut to run this code

```
cd /Applications/Thunderbird.app/Contents/MacOS/
./thunderbird -compose "CLIPBOARD CONTENT"
```

I would like to use this to automatically create an email based on the (dynamic) content of the spreadsheet.

Is this possible or does anyone have a better idea how to create such emails? I have tried to work with mailto-links but it does not work because there is some more complexity to the spreadsheet which makes it impossible.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not a Mac user, and not very sure of this, but maybe copying the line, and combine this with `inputrc` could do the trick

Comment: You can do this with an Automator Quick Action

Comment: I have played around with Automator a little but I don't see where I can add the clipboard content to a task. Plus, when I run the command via the script 'building block' it opens Thunderbird but gets stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: It should not be necessary to `cd`, and I would almost regard it as an error. Try simply `/Applications/Thunderbird.app/Contents/MacOS/thunderbird -compose "CLIPBOARD CONTENT"`

Comment: Where do you have a spreadsheet in all this?

Answer (score 0):

This workflow works from within Automator (even though I feel it's kind of buggy). Unfortunately, when I call it using a shortcut from within other apps it throws an error:

[image: Error]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the cause of my error 212:

The `of front workflow` statement does not work from outside Automator because then, it is not the front workflow anymore. I had to do a workaround that does not use this statement...